Iterating over ranges defined by a pair of integer arrays
I have a multidimensional array $\boldsymbol{A}$ of values and want to calculate the sum of values for every orthogonal range.
The orthogonal ranges are defined by a pair of "antipodal" corners $\left(x_0,\,\dots,\,x_{n-1}\right),\left(x_0+c_0,\,\dots,\,x_{n-1}+c_{n-1}\right);\quad x_i,c_i\in \mathbb{N}_0 $
What want to do is to calculate the sum $\sum\limits_{i_{n-1}=x_{n-1}}^{x_{n-1}+c_{n-1}}\cdots\sum\limits_{i_0=x_{0}}^{x_{0}+c_{0}}\boldsymbol{A}\left[i_0,\,\dots,\,i_{n-1}\right]$, however in a more "pythonic" way in the vein of
sum([A[i] for i in range(x,x+c)]) # pseudo code!

is there a way to convert the above pseudo code into valid python code by means of the itertools or numpy library?
